# Why when I create this CSS rule `h1 {font-family: Tahoma}`it doesn't work?

Tags: css, font-family

I have an exam that asks me to "update the following CSS code so that all level 1 headings, level 2 headings, and paragraph elements use the "Tahoma" font. Then, reset the box model for all CSS elements to border-box."

I searched for a solution to this specific problem, asked other colleagues, and everyone agrees that the code is correct.

That is the original code:

```
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 50px 60px;
}

h1 {
  color: #007E49;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#gameboard {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 30px;
}

.card {
  border: 2px solid #9DD1F1;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 215px;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: #004E89;
  border-color: #004E89;
}

.card img {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

I tried this but the system says that I "didn't define  font-family element to Tahoma":

```
h1, h2, p {
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 50px 60px;
}

h1 {
  color: #007E49;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#gameboard {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 30px;
}

.card {
  border: 2px solid #9DD1F1;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 215px;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: #004E89;
  border-color: #004E89;
}

.card img {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it wants you to use `@font-face`?

Comment: Tahoma is one of the common "web safe" fonts that ship with most operating systems, and defining it as part of `font-family` should suffice. Where is this error message  `didn't define font-family element to Tahoma` coming from? Have you tried testing in a browser? I suspect it'd render the fonts properly.

Comment: Edit your question to include a screen shot of the error, and explain where you're seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

It did accept this code :

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 50px 60px;
}

h1, h2, p {
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif; 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).